# How to represent a column name with a variable in join of Spark data frame in R?

Tags: r, join, sparkr

Let say there are two columns in my dataset:
Dataset Table1

```
Name Eng
A 10
B 20
```

Dataset Table2

```
Name Maths
A 30
B 40
```

Using SparkR,

```
table_merged = join(Table1,Table2,(table1$Name == table2$Name))
```

However, if I store the column name in a variable

```
var = "Name"
```

what would be the equivalent command to do the same ?

Comment: `table1[[var]]==table2[[var]]`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe easier will be use one of 'join' from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
var = "Name"
table_merged <- left_join(Table1,Table2, by = var)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is for a spark dataframe on R so the above command doesn't work.

table_merged = merge(Table1,Table2, by = var)

A similar command works though.